# When should I start and stop my notification service?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I don't want the notification service to be working while the user is in the application.  As of right now I have it starting in the onCreate and onResume methods and stopping in the onPause method.  Is that correct?

Also, is it sufficient to specify the intent and execute stopService(intent) to stop it?  There isn't a direct relationship between the start and stop methods except they reference the same class.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: It appears I only need to start it in the onResume method.  I will make that change unless someone tells me otherwise.

Comment: Well I think its best to clarify the question. Why are you staring it in onResume if your goal is to turn it off while the user is using your application. When do you want it off/on thats the first thing we need to know to answer the question.

Comment: Second question's answer - yes. First question, you need to understand activity lifecycle here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html there is an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) is the activity lifecycle.

As you will see, `onCreate()` and `onResume()` are called before the activity is created so you do not want to start your notification service there. You should stop it instead. It is a good idea to do it once in `onResume()` because it is the entry point of your activity.

`onPause()` is where user navigates away from the activity so it is where you will want to start the service again.

Comment: I wrote my question backwards.  That is exactly what I thought.  I am stopping it onResume and starting it onPause.  Thank you for your help.